# $\forall x\in \left(0,\infty\right),\ \exists y\in\left(0,\infty\right)\ \text{ s.t. } xy = 1$

Tags: logic, proof-verification

Prove if the statement is true

$$\forall x\in \left(0,\infty\right),\ \exists y\in\left(0,\infty\right)\ \text{ s.t. } xy = 1$$

For the statement above, I argued that this is false because if x = 0, then 0*y = 1 is false. Hence, the statement is false. I also argued that the negation of the statement above which is:

$$\exists x\in \left(0,\infty\right),\ \forall y\in\left(0,\infty\right)\ \text{ s.t. } xy \neq 1$$

is true. Therefore, if the negation is true, the original statement is false.

---

However, the answer provided says is true for

Let $x \in \left(0,\infty\right)$, Then $y = x^{-1}\in \left(0,\infty\right)$ and satisfies $xy=1$.

I'm much confused.

Comment: You cannot take $x=0$ as counterexample, since the statement only applies to $x \in (0,\infty)$ (i.e., $x > 0$).

Comment: The statement says: for every positive real $x$ there is a positive real $y$ such that $xy = 1$.

Comment: @Clement C 
I thought x∈(0,∞) would mean x are elements in the domain from 0 to ∞ and 0 would be in that domain. no?

Comment: [No: the usual meaning of the notation $(a,b)$ for an interval is "excluding the endpoints $a$ and $b$." Including both would be $[a,b]$; including $a$ and excluding $b$ would be $[a,b)$; etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals)

Comment: The notation $(0,+\infty)$ means open interval, you are not considering the extreme points $0,+\infty$; if you want to include the $0$ it is usually written as $[0,+\infty)$.

Comment: Square brackets indicate the inclusion of an endpoint in an interval, round ones, exclusion. So $[0,1]$ is all $x$ with $0 \le x \le 1$, and $(0,1]$ is all $x$ with $0 < x \le 1$. Similarly for and $[0,)$ and $(0,1)$.

Comment: Just a note about your notation: The correct syntax would be: $\forall x \in(0,\infty):\exists y\in(0,\infty):xy=1$. Neither the comma nor "s.t." are appropriate and you most definitely shouldn't mix the two. A colon is all you need. And $(a,b)$ usually means all real number between $a$ and $b$ not including $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification guys. I had forgotten about the pesky open and closed interval brackets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x \in (a , b)$ is usually interpreted to mean $a < x < b$, so $x \in (0, \infty)$ is interpreted to mean $0 < x$.

The Theorem you are trying to prove is one of the [axioms of a Field structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)), the existence of a multiplicative inverse, and one of the axioms of Real Numbers is that they form a field.

Answer (score 1):

Proof:

Let $x\in(0,\infty)$ and $y:=1/x$. Then $y\in(0,\infty)$ and $xy=1$. Thus $\forall x \in(0,\infty):\exists y\in(0,\infty):xy=1$.